# Sort the Fabrics Google Kickstart Challenge - Samples Passed, but Wrong Answer on Test 1 (Python)

Tags: python

Edit: Here’s the link to the original problem: https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/00000000008cb409/0000000000beefbb

On Round F of Google's 2022 Kick Start challenges, one of the tasks was to create an algorithm that sorts a list of fabrics through two methods: by color (in alphabetical order), and by durability. Upon inputting T test cases, N fabrics, and the color, durability, and unique ID integer of each fabric, the program outputs the number of times that the fabrics were sorted into the same position regardless of the sorting method.

When I wrote this code and tried it on the sample input, it worked perfectly. But when I submitted the code, it only passed the samples and failed the first test.

Now that the contest is over, I'd like to learn how I could have improved my code so that it would have passed both tests.

The Python I wrote is below:

```
import operator
        
def sort():
    N = int(input())
    my_fabric = []
    fabric_list = []
    i = 0
    while i < N:
        input_fabric = str(input())
        split_list = input_fabric.split(' ')
        color = split_list[0]
        dura = split_list[1]
        ident = split_list[2]
        my_fabric.append(color)
        my_fabric.append(dura)
        my_fabric.append(ident)
        fabric_list.append(my_fabric)
        my_fabric = []
        i += 1
    return fabric_list

def ada(fabric_list):
    ada_list = sorted(fabric_list, key = operator.itemgetter(0))
    return ada_list

def charles(fabric_list):
    charles_list = sorted(fabric_list, key = operator.itemgetter(1))
    return charles_list

def comparison(ada_list, charles_list):
    list_len = len(ada_list)
    i = 0
    same_counter = 0
    while i < list_len: 
        if ada_list[i] == charles_list[i]:
            ada_list = sorted(ada_list, key = operator.itemgetter(2))
            charles_list = sorted(charles_list, key = operator.itemgetter(2))
            if ada_list[i][2] == charles_list[i][2]:
                same_counter += 1
                i += 1
            else:
                i += 1
        else:
            i += 1
    return same_counter

def main():
    t = int(input())
    i = 0
    while i < t:
        fabric_list = sort()
        ada_list = ada(fabric_list)
        charles_list = charles(fabric_list)
        same_counter = comparison(ada_list, charles_list)
        print("Case #{}: {}".format(i+1, same_counter))
        i += 1

main()
```

Any advice you can give is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, updated with a link to the original problem.

Comment: they don't show data used in tests so it hard to say where is the problem. Maybe it is only problem with speed. OR maybe some unique data makes problem (some `extreme cases`). You may try to create own data and test your code  - maybe some of your data will show problem with code.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to turn the number strings into numbers (using `int()` just like for `T` and `N`) so they get compared as such (instead of lexicographically). Also, you made it quite complicated. Just build a list of the split lines, sort them the two ways using each way's two criteria, and count equals:

```
T = int(input())
for x in range(1, T+1):
    N = int(input())
    fabrics = [input().split() for _ in range(N)]
    ada = sorted(fabrics, key=lambda f: (f[0], int(f[2])))
    charles = sorted(fabrics, key=lambda f: (int(f[1]), int(f[2])))
    same = sum(a == c for a, c in zip(ada, charles))
    print(f'Case #{x}:', same)
```

Alternatively, and quite possibly faster, you could first sort only by ID, and then only by color or durability. That will also break ties by ID, as the sorting algorithm is stable:

```
T = int(input())
for x in range(1, T+1):
    N = int(input())
    fabrics = [input().split() for _ in range(N)]
    fabrics.sort(key=lambda f: int(f[2]))
    ada = sorted(fabrics, key=lambda f: f[0])
    charles = sorted(fabrics, key=lambda f: int(f[1]))
    same = sum(a == c for a, c in zip(ada, charles))
    print(f'Case #{x}:', same)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use convert string to integer.
3 < 10 and '10' < '3'

you can use the below sample to understand the problem.

```
1
2
blue 3 1
yellow 10 2
```

This is my code:
https://github.com/alwynroy009/GoogleKickstart2022/blob/main/SortTheFabrics.py

And this is my explanation:
https://youtu.be/eUD7f3zrch0

Hope this is helpful :)